# Sendgrid Azure Function to send out single email to list of users from html form

Tags: python, azure-functions, sendgrid

I am trying to send out an email from a Azure function using Sendgrid and python however, I don't want users to see everyone it is being sent to.  I have tried using personalizations but I keep getting an errors. I think it has to do with this line `response = sg.send(msg)`.  These are the error messages when I try to use the personalizations:

```
[2023-08-04T18:53:00.718Z] Executed 'Functions.EmailExample' (Failed, Id=89635dc0-d0be-416c-bd13-71be593d87b4, Duration=578ms)
[2023-08-04T18:53:00.720Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.EmailExample. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: BadRequestsError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 448, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\name_redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 691, in _run_sync_func
    return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
    result = function(**args)
  File "C:\Users\name_redacted\OneDrive\Desktop\sfpracticev1\EmailExample\__init__.py", line 63, in main
    response = sg.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\name_redacted\OneDrive\Desktop\sfpracticev1\lib\site-packages\sendgrid\base_interface.py", line 62, in send
    return self.client.mail.send.post(request_body=message)
  File "C:\Users\name_redacted\OneDrive\Desktop\sfpracticev1\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 277, in http_request
    self._make_request(opener, request, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\name_redacted\OneDrive\Desktop\sfpracticev1\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 184, in _make_request
    raise exc
```

I have tried a few different ways, but I feel like this is very close. However, I am pretty new and I could be waaaay off base here.

Eventually we will be using different templates, the template I am provding is just a testing purposes.

(please be gentle I am a newbie, I just graduated with a CS degree in May)

This is my current code, it definately works it will send emails to everyone listed in the email form but everyone can see everyone else it is sent to, if I try personalizations I get the error I added above.

**init**.py

```
import logging
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (Mail, Email, To, Content, Attachment,
                                   FileContent, FileName, FileType,
                                   Disposition, ContentId, reply_to, Cc, Bcc, 
                                   Personalization, SendGridException)
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
import azure.functions as func

required = ["sender_email", "recipients", "message", "subject"]

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Mailing Function received new request.')

    data = req.form.to_dict()

    if not data:
        return func.HttpResponse("ERROR: No input data.")

    missing = []
    for key in required:
        if key not in data:
            missing.append(key)

    if len(missing):
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"ERROR: Missing required inputs: {','.join(missing)}")
    
    sender_email = data["sender_email"]
    email = data["recipients"].split(",")
    cc = data["cc"].split(",") if "cc" in data else None
    # bcc = data["bcc"]
    subject = data["subject"]
    message = data["message"]

    msg = Mail(
        from_email=sender_email,
        to_emails=email,
        subject=subject,
        is_multiple=True,
        plain_text_content= message
    )

    p = Personalization()

    if cc:
        for c in cc:
        #     p = Personalization()
        #     p.add_email(Cc(c))
        # msg.add_personalization(p)
            msg.add_cc(Cc(c))

    # for r in email:
    #     p = Personalization()
    #     p.add_email(To(r))
    # msg.add_personalization(p)
    #    msg.add_to(To([r]))
    try: 
        apikey = os.environ["SENDGRID_API_KEY"]
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key=apikey)
        response = sg.send(msg)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)

        return func.HttpResponse("Email sent sucessfully")
    except SendGridException as e:
        print(e.read())
```

The form I am using:
email_form.html

```
<form action="Azure URL" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <label for="sender_email">Sender Email</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="sender_email"
        class="form-control"
        id="sender_email"
        placeholder="Your email"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
      <label for="recipients">To Email</label>
      <input
        type="email" multiple
        class="form-control"
        name="recipients"
        id="recipients"
        placeholder="To Email"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
    <label for="cc">CC Email</label>
    <input
      type="email" multiple
      class="form-control"
      name="cc"
      id="cc"
      placeholder="CC: "
    />
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="subject"
      class="form-control"
      id="subject"
      placeholder="subject"
      required
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <textarea
      class="form-control"
      name="message"
      rows="5"
      placeholder="message"
      required
    ></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
  </script>
</form>
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["get", "post"]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```